# Java connection to HSQLDB without server being started

Tags: java, jdbc, hsqldb

I'm connecting to the HSQLDB server using the following:

```
private static Connection connectionToServer () throws SQLException {
    try {
        Class.forName("org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("ERROR: failed to load HSQLDB JDBC driver.");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);
}
```

Why does this return a connection that I can use to create tables even if the hsqldb server has not been started at the specified DB_URL with those credentials?

Comment: Report the value for DB_URL.

Comment: URL is currently
`"jdbc:hsqldb:mem:dbtestingname"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The URL "jdbc:hsqldb:mem:dbtestingname" creates an in-process database in your application's JVM process. This is not a server.

If you want a separate server, you have to start it separately. You then connect to the server with something like: "jdbc:hsqldb:hsql:dbtestserver"